# How do I adjust a column length in postgreSQL DB with a Datamapper migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, datamapper

I'm using [dm-migrations](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-migrations/) to create a custom migration for my database.

However, I can't seem to find an example of modifying the length of a column. Can someone please explain how this done? I'm using a postgresql database on rails 3.

UPDATE:

I've tried the following:

```
migration 1, :modify_course_url_length do
  up do
    modify_table :hotels do
      change_column :url, String, :length => 255
    end
  end
end
```

but it looks as though I need to get `change_column_type_statement` method working since its a postgresql db.

UPDATE 2:

It seems the problem is that the outputted SQL is:

ALTER TABLE "hotels" ALTER COLUMN "url" VARCHAR(255)

whilst it needs to be

ALTER TABLE "hotels" ALTER COLUMN "url" TYPE VARCHAR(255)

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just write the raw SQL for the migration instead, like so...

```
migration 1, :modify_course_url_length do
  up do
    execute(<<-SQL)
    ALTER TABLE hotels ALTER COLUMN url TYPE VARCHAR(255)
    SQL
  end
end
```